# React-native how to refresh scene after pop

Tags: react-native

I would like to re-render scene after click back button on a previous scene without using flux or redux.

```
    export default class testNote extends Component {

    renderScene(route, navigator){

        switch(route.id){
            case 'NotesList':
                return(<NotesList navigator={navigator} title="NotesList"/>);
            case 'addNote':
                return(<AddNote navigator={navigator}  title="AddNote" />)
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (

            <Navigator
                initialRoute={{id: 'NotesList'}}
                renderScene={this.renderScene}
                configureScene={(route,routeStack)=>Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight}

            />

        );
    }
}
```

From scene 'adNote' I return to previous scene 'notesList' using this function.

```
backScene(){
        this.state.navigator.pop();
    }
```

Is it possible to re-render scene 'notesList'.
Thank you.

Comment: try using componentWillReceiveProps or componentWillUpdate. Then inside them you will have to reconize 'why' the component is being update, and in that case refresh info, re-render, or whatever you need

Comment: Thank you to give me idea to use this functions but now I'm straggle how to set a proper 'why' option in function. Is there any way to detect how component was render after 'pop()' function or 'push()'? Regards.